# How to modify an Azure B2C user through Azure Functions using Microsoft Graph

Tags: azure-functions, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

Is it possible to get an Azure AD B2C user ID in a protected Azure function, and then update that user's attributes from the function using the Microsoft Graph API? How can this be done?

The protected function API is being accessed by an [Angular SPA using MSAL](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-javascript-angular-spa).

Answer (score 0):

[Edit based on further explanation of question]

So I am assuming you have the access token as a result of authentication from B2C. You will need to pass it in Authorization Header to Azure Function and make a REST call with updated user info (preferably a PATCH call).

The Azure function can use the Authorization Header to [validate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.identitymodel.tokens.jwt.jwtsecuritytokenhandler.validatetoken?view=azure-dotnet) the token. There are many samples over internet on how to validate a token.

Once you validate the token, the objectId claim in the token can be used to identify the  user by the Azure function.

Now you need to make an app only (client credential) call from Azure Function to patch the user. The Microsoft Graph api for user modification is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0). The Microsoft Graph sample to use client credential is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service). 
Create a web application in Azure AD app registration blade. Generate a client secret for this app and assign the appropriate app only permission to this app. From Azure function, use this clientId and client secret to  get a token from Azure AD for Microsoft Graph and then call Microsoft Graph with that token.

Comment: This article looks like it deals more with information being validated from a user flow type of page (not the Angular app). How can an Azure function modify a B2C user using the Microsoft Graph API, with information it received directly from Angular, instead a Microsoft B2C user flow page?

Comment: Then the question is not clear. Could you please explain the scenario?

Comment: How can an Azure function tell which user is calling it through MSAL.js, and then use the Microsoft Graph API specifically to update that user in Azure AD B2C? Instead of using an "Edit Profile" user flow, how can the Angular app send the updated profile information to the Azure function? The Azure function has authentication turned on, and is configured to be protected by Azure AD B2C.